# Magento 2: Using nginx -- All Static Assets are 404

Tags: magento2, php, nginx, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to install Magento 2 using the Laravel Homestead project.  Laravel Homestead provides a virtual machine based around nginx.  I have nginx successfully serving Magento 2 application pages.  **However**, nginx is **not** serving static asset files.  They all 404.

```
curl -I 'http://magento-php7.dev/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css'
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.9.9
Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 22:13:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

I think what's happening in nginx is skipping the `pub/static/.htaccess` file that makes the static asset serving application work.  If I make a direct call to the URL that `pub/static/.htaccess` redirect to, the asset serves successfully

```
http://magento-php7.dev/static.php?resource=frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?  [This page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/) on the nginx wiki makes it sound like nginx doesn't support .htaccess -- but the root `.htaccess/mod_rewrite` is working fine. (it may be homestead is providng magic for this -- I just don't know nginx well enough to know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn out `nginx` doesn't read `.htaccess` files.  The default Laravel homestead configuration took care of rewriting to the main `index.php` file, but not for the `static.php` file.

You'll need to replace the laravel provided configuration with one based on `nginx.conf.sample`.  The `nginx.conf.sample` is distributed in the root Magento 2 folder.

Comment: Means required to add `nginx.conf.sample` instead of `.htaccess`?

Comment: Only homepage working. Admin and front other page not open. It through 404 error.

Answer (score 3):

Alan Storm & Manelio are pointing you in the correct direction. Basically nginx is not doing a rewrite on the `/static` sub-directory. This below code is likely all you need added to your nginx.conf file which controls your Magento 2 installation:

```
location /static/ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my /static/ location block, but it is from a bit older versión of Magento 2, I think.

```
location /static/ {
    if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
        expires max;
    }
    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
}
```

I think the last rewrite is the one relevant for you.

Answer (score -2):

- Manually remove pub/static/frontend and pub/static/adminhtml
- Run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy in the Magento root directory
- Run bin/magento cache:clean
- Set file permission for pub folder 770 for folders and 660 for files